# How do I search for a set amount of hex and non hex data in python

Tags: python, regex, hex

I have a string that looks like this

```
'\x00\x03\x10B\x00\x0e12102 G1103543\x10T\x07\x21'
```

I have been able to match the data I want which is "12102 G1103543" with this.

```
re.findall('\x10\x42(.*)\x10\x54', data)
```

Which will output this

```
'\x00\x0e12102 G1103543'
```

The problem im having is that \x10\x54 is not always at the end of the data I want. However what I have noticed is that the first two hex digits correspond to how long the data length will be. I.E. \x00\x0e = 14 so the data length is 14char long.

Is there a better way to do this, like matching the first part then cutting the next 14 characters? I should also say that the length will vary as im looking to match several things.

Also is there a way to output the string in all hex so its easier for me to read when working in a python shell I.E. \x10B == \x10\x42

Thank You!

Edit: I managed to come up with this working solution.

```
newdata = re.findall('\x10\x42(.*)', data)
newdata[0][2:int(newdata[0][0:2].encode('hex'))]
```

Comment: if you can safely determine where the length is stored, you should cut the next digits from there on

Comment: Should have known I needed to try a little harder.

Comment: Do this as a procedure, rather than looking at the whole file from above. Your loop should be: 1. read 2 bytes, 2. interpret them as the length of the following message, 3. read that many bytes, 4. goto 1

Answer (score 0):

Please, note that you have an structured binary file at your hands, and it is foolish to try to use regular expressions to extract data from it.

First of all the "hex data" you talk about is not "hex data" -it is just bytes
in your stream outside the ASCII range - therefore Python2 will display these characters as a `\x10` and so on - but internally it is just a single byte with the  value 16 (when viewed as decimal). The `\x42`you write corresponds to the ASCII letter `B` and that is why you see `B` in your representation.

So your best bet there would be to get the file specification, and read the data you want from there using the `struct` module and byte-string slicing.

If you can't have the file spec, so it is a reverse-engineering work to find out the fields of interest -just like you are already doing. But even then, you should write some code with the struct module to get your values, since field lenghts (and most likely offsets) are encoded in the byte stream itself.

In this example, your marker "\x10\x42" will rarely be a marker per se - it is most likely its position is indicated by other factors in the file (either a fixed place in the file definition, or by an offset earlier on the file.

But - if you are correctly using this as a marker, you could make use of regular expressions just to findout all offsets of the "\x10\x42" marker as you are doing, and them interpreting the following two bytes as the message length:

```
import struct, re

def get_data(data, sep=b"\x10B"):
    results = []
    for match in re.finditer(sep, data):
        offset = match.start()
        msglen = struct.unpack(">H", data[offset + 2: offset + 4])[0]
        print(msglen)
        results.append(data[offset + 4: offset + 4 + msglen])
    return results
```